# csv to list and analyze python

Tags: python, list, csv, count

I am reading some values in from a csv file and converting those values to a list with the following code. The csv file is just one row, of around 2000 values that are either a "1" or a "0". With the code I am trying to count how many of the number of "1"'s there are in the csv file.

```
def countX(a, x):
    count = 0
    for ele in a:
        if (ele == x):
            count = count + 1
    return count

def countX(a, x):
    return a.count(x)

with open(my_file_name, 'r') as in1file:
    mylist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(in1file, delimiter=';')]

print (mylist)

a = [mylist]
x = 1

countX 
print(countX(a, x))
```

The issue I have is that "my list" returns something like

```
['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']
```

So when I interrogate my list to count the tally of "1"'s, I am always getting the value 0 for some reason. If i just create a list and make

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

I will get a counted value of 6. How can I make this work so I get the number of 1's counted from my csv file?

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: Apologies, I have just amended it

Comment: Your variable names are very poorly chosen and make it hard to read the code.

Comment: Also, FYR, there is a function `list.count(x)` that counts `x` in a list. There is no need to reimplement it.

Comment: how do you implement list.count(x)?

Comment: If i have a list called MyList and want to find how many of the elements within my list are equal to 1 how would i write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> MyList = ['0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']
>>> counts = Counter(MyList[0].split(','))
>>> counts
Counter({'0': 18, '1': 2})
>>> counts['1']
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `delimiter` named param to `,` in your code.

So the code to read the CSV would be:

```
with open(my_file_name, 'r') as in1file:
    mylist = csv.reader(in1file, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: When I try changing the delimiter my list just return ['0']

Answer (score 0):

Your list only contains a single string right now. You need to take the string and do a `split(',')` on it, which will give you a list of single-character strings, then you can cast those to integers, which I think is what you want.

If that really is your `mylist`, and it's of length 1, then here's my thinking:

```
>>> mylist = ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'] 
>>> mylist[0]
'0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
>>> [int(item) for item in mylist[0].split(',')]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If `mylist` has a lot of strings like that one in it, you can do something like:

```
lines = []
for line in mylist:
    lines.append([int(item) for item in line.split(',')])
```

Comment: Like this? I am still getting a value of "0"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet that works for your case:

```
MyList = ['0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']
MyList_Split = MyList[0].split(',')
print(MyList_Split.count('1'))
# Returns 2
```

Comment: This cured it for me, thank you for all your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def countX(a, x):
count = 0
for ele in a:
    if (ele == x):
        count = count + 1
return count

def countX(a, x):
return a.count(x)

with open(my_file_name, 'r') as in1file:
mylist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(in1file, delimiter=';')]

new_list = [int(item) for item in mylist[0].split(',')]

a = [new_list]
x = 1

countX 
print(countX(a, x))
```